# How do i call method from another class with parameter?

Tags: android

I'm a beginner Android programming. How do I call method from another class with parameter.

I tried with method()it work. but I don't know how to with parameter

@class b

```
public class GetUrl {
static Context context;
public GetUrl(Context c) {
    context = c;

}
public String getJSONUrl(String url) {
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
    try {
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
        int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
        if (statusCode == 200) { // Download OK
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream content = entity.getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                str.append(line);
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("Log", "Failed to download result..");
        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return str.toString();
}
}
```

I want to call in Class A

In class A how to call it?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [this site](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/) to learn the basics.

```
public class A(){
        public A(){   //Empty constructor
        }

        public void someMethod(){
        }

        public void someMethodThatTakesString(String string){
        //do something with the string passed
        }

        public static void anotherMethod(){
        }
    }
    //You call this class and it's method
    A.anotherMethod(); //because this method is static
    A classA = new A();
    classA.someMethod();
    String someString = "I am string"
    classA.someMethodThatTakesString(someString)
```

Answer (score 0):

By creating instance of this class

```
A a = new A();
```

Or with static methods

```
A.method(params);`
```

Comment: In Java you don't need instance of the class to access public static methods, fields etc but you need instance of the class to access non static methods, fields etc

Comment: Yeah, I mean if method is static you can do this without creating an instance, but if not, you got to.